# How create new class from Class<?>?

Tags: java, android, class

Just out of curiosity. How can I create a new class from Class where the constructor does not require parameters? Here's an example:

```
public static BroadcastReceiver startBroadcastReceiver(Context context, Class<?> receiverClass, String receiverTag) {
    BroadcastReceiver receiver = null;

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(receiverTag);

    receiver = new receiverClass(); // <---- What's the correct syntax?

    if (receiver != null && intentFilter != null) {
        context.registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
    }

    return receiver;
}
```

Here's how I would call it:

```
MyTools.startBroadcastReceiver(context, MyBroadcastReceiver, MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `receiverClass.newInstance();`?

Comment: You want to create *class* or new *object* of class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
try{
    receiver = (BroadcastReceiver) receiverClass.newInstance();
}catch(Exception e){
    //do stuff
}
```

And you will call it

```
MyTools.startBroadcastReceiver(context, MyBroadcastReceiver.class, MyBroadcastReceiver.TAG);
```

Comment: If you change the type of receiverClass to Class<? extends BroadcastReceiver>. This makes the call type-safe and avoids casting.